# pywinauto.keyboard.KeySequenceError: `}` should be preceeded by `{`

Tags: keyboard, pywinauto

Have the following code, it outputs the generated password to the command line (using the print command) but when I send the generated password to the password text box I get the error

**pywinauto.keyboard.KeySequenceError: `}` should be preceeded by `{`**

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title = "SKF Insight Rail Manager")
```

app.top_window().set_focus()

```
password = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
password += random.choice(string.punctuation)
password += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
password += random.choice(string.digits)
for i in range(4):
    randomSource = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password += random.choice(randomSource)
```

Comment: I have added the keys {} as hardcoded because when randomly generating the password the key sequence }{ gave me the above error

Answer (score 0):

Curly brackets is a kind of escape sequence. You need to unescape them by wrapping with `{}`. In your case it should look so:

```
password = "{}}" # wrap by {} for send_keys
password += "{{}" # wrap by {} for send_keys
password += random.choice(string.digits)
password += random.choice(string.punctuation)
for i in range(4):
    randomSource = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password += random.choice(randomSource)

# tricky replace is needed for human readable form of password
print("Generated password:" + password.replace('{}}', '}').replace('{{}', '{'))

time.sleep(1)

keyboard.send_keys(password)
```

The docs about send_keys: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html

Comment: thanks, that works when it is harcoded.  I've updated the code with what I actually want to work and if it randomly selects '}' as the punctuation (rather than hardcoded like previously), how do I get that to work ?  Still get the same error